# Other than Alpha and Delta, were there any other types of androids in Total Recall 2070?

Tags: total-recall-2070

The plot of the TV series *Total Recall 2070* implies that there are a variety of different types of androids.

> Hume's partner, Ian Farve, is secretly a type of android called an 'Alpha'

Almost all of the workers are called 'Deltas'.

Does the series or any of the supporting materials mention any other types of androids?

Comment: The "list" is going to be really short and un-subjective.

Comment: I'm curious to who cast the close vote.  Other than being a slightly obscure question,  how is this in anyway not a perfect question for this site?

Comment: Let's make a list of these three things? I'm just not clear how this is an actual *question*, per "What kinds of questions should I not ask here?" in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Have you seen Total Recall 2070?  There are only two types of androids directly referenced in the series.  I'm trying to see if there are any mention of the other types of andriods.  There are only a few types of androids in the series and the types of robots has a special meaning in the series.  I think that you have decided to close the question because you have not seen the series and do not understand the question.

Comment: @Jeff - why did you close this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about Betas?

[Various cast lists](http://epguides.com/TotalRecall2070/guide.shtml) suggest a Beta Android, notably that played by Kevin Hare in Episode 11 *Begotten Not Made (2)*.  Hare also played an android in Episode 5 *Allure* as a doorman, and in Episode 20 *Personal Effects*.  [Some lists](http://www.tvrage.com/shows/id-6389/printable/) also have Kevin Rushton as a Beta Android in Episode 6 *Infiltration*.

A [German summary](http://www.serienheaven.de/fertige_serien/t/totalrecall2070/totalrecall2070_1.htm) of Episodes 1 & 2 *Machine Dreams* seems to suggest that Beta Androids were behind the murder of the teenagers, though I am not sure that is correct.